# Downloading a text file

Tags: java, android

I am trying to download a text file in Android, i know how to load image file, how different is text file downloading from it?
Moerover how to retrive contents from the downloaded file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking a few things, this should give you an idea of how to get a remote file using urlconnection and associated classes

```
URL u = new URL(url);
                        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();

                        URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();

                        fs = conn.getContentLength();

                        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                        c.setDoOutput(true);
                        c.connect();

                        String PATH_op = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() 
                                +"//"+ filename;

                        f = new FileOutputStream(new File(PATH_op));

                        InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                        int len1 = 0;

                        while ( (len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                            f.write(buffer,0, len1);
                            completed += len1; 
                        }

                        f.close();`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

There will be no difference in downloading the text file or image or XML. every thing is same. but the usage after getting the stream depends on the type of the content.

If its a Image we will decode the stream to convert it to an image.

If its a Text we need to read the content character by character until the whole content got read or got -1 as the character which denotes the end of the file.

When coming to the XML file file we will directly pass the input stream object to Parser.